# iOS Error - CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I have a phonegap app that has always worked fine, now I am getting the following message in the log, does anybody have any idea what this could be?

CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm getting this when I play a youtube video in a UIWebview on ios7.  Seemed to be fine on ios6.  Memory consumption very high when this occurs (40MB).  Looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

These messages appear when (double)tapping textfield. Sometimes there are other cases when similar messages can appear, but it looks like they comes from internal components like webview or textfield, so I mostly ignore them(I check if my code can cause troubles first and if it's not the source of errors - I ignore these messages).

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599266/invalid-context-0x0-under-ios-7-0-and-system-degradation) are some helpful answers.

Answer (score -1):

use NSZombie to find error and track what is going wrong