# Invalid Context 0x0 when dismissing a UIImageView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

When I try to dismiss a `UIImageView` with

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(_tutorial.frame, p)) {
        _tutorial.hidden = YES;

        _transButton.enabled = YES;
        _transButtonEng.enabled = YES;
        _infoButton.enabled = YES;
        _textfield.enabled = YES;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"HOW IS THIS EVEN POSSIBLE?!?!?"); //The CGRect is the whole screen
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

> MacBook-Pro.local APP_NAME[97086] : CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

It also repeats the same message with `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor:` replaced by:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor:
CGContextSaveGState:
CGContextSetFlatness:
CGContextAddPath:
CGContextDrawPath:
CGContextRestoreGState:
CGContextSaveGState:
CGContextSetFlatness:
CGContextAddPath:
CGContextDrawPath:
CGContextRestoreGState:
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor:
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor:
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor:
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor:
CGContextGetBlendMode:
CGContextSetBlendMode:
CGContextFillRects:
CGContextSetBlendMode:
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor:
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor:
CGContextGetBlendMode:
CGContextSetBlendMode:
CGContextFillRects:
CGContextSetBlendMode:
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor:
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor:
CGContextGetBlendMode:
CGContextSetBlendMode:
CGContextFillRects:
CGContextSetBlendMode:
```

I am using the latest version of Xcode 5 and iOS 7.0.3.

How would I fix these errors?

Comment: In the code that you've copied to your question, you should also include the method / function that has the call to "`CGContextSetFillColorWithColor`".

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I don't call any of these anywhere; I use Interface Builder

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but there are known iOS 7 bugs that cause this sort of behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599266/invalid-context-0x0-under-ios-7-0-and-system-degradation/19599686#19599686

Comment: I have seen these, but I was wondering if there was a fix for when UIGestureRecognizer/UIImageView cause the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you hide your `_tutorial` imageView, you should remove the gesture recognizer (via UIGestureRecgonizer's ["`removeTarget: action:`" API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/removeTarget%3aaction%3a), so that way you won't be calling "`CGRectContainsPoint`" on a hidden view with who knows what for frame values.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I have much trouble reading most types of API Docs.