# A load of CGContext errors for no apparent reason

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been working on this project for the last week and everything has been running fine in the simulator. Just this evening when I went to run it, I got this whole raft of brand new errors, and the only code that I have added since the last smooth build / simulation was the following to add a dictionary from a file that I just created.

I am definitely in the steep part of the learning curve on Objective-C and Xcode, and these errors do not ring a bell at all because I haven't used any of the code that these refer to in my project, unless they somehow relate to code that is created behind the scenes during UI design in the storyboard. Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is the code that I used to add my dictionary:

```
    - (void)calculate
    {
        // Retrieve the dictionary containing the chart
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chart" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSDictionary *chart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];


    }
```

And here is the error log:

```
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextGetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextGetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextGetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Jan  5 02:40:46 Cs-MacBook-Pro.local Project[3731] <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

Comment: Loading a dictionary from a plist and the `CGContext` errors are unrelated unless you're using the dictionary to then draw something.

Comment: Yeah I am not doing anything with any drawing functionality, so it must be unrelated, which is what I was guessing in the first place. Judging from the later answer here and the others related on this forum, I may just have to live with them for the time being... Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known error in iOS7... just let it be like this...If i am right, this will not show up everytime. No workaround is available at this time. try to upgrade to 7.0.3. for more info look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599266/invalid-context-0x0-under-ios-7-0-and-system-degradation). You can find tons of such questions on StackOverflow.. Don't worry.. keep working.. Let me know if you are still unhappy with my answer. ..:) I know its not easy to digest, but you have to..:(

Comment: Oh man. That is SO unsatisfying. :/ OK I am getting the errors right now but I will let them slide for the time being. The app I am working on will be done in the next week or so, knock on wood. I don't see 7.0.3 available as of yet, so I am assuming it is in beta right now. Thanks for your help!