# UISlider setMaximumTrackTintColor in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, uislider

```
[slider setMaximumTrackTintColor: color]
```

has unexpected results in iOS 7.1 (the slider bar changes its position appearing at top instead of vertical center or disappears completely), while working fine with prior versions.

```
[slider setMinimumTrackTintColor: color]
```

does render the expected result.

This question might be related: [UISlider setMaximumTrackTintColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683348/uislider-setmaximumtracktintcolor),
but no answer so far.

**Update:**

I get this: [image: wrong] instead of: [image]

**Update #2:**

Using `setMaximumTrackImage` might work, but the solution I'm looking for is a way to set **any random color** and not a preexisting image.

**Update #3:**

This issue is still present in **iOS 7.1.1**.

Comment: explain brief about what you get?

Comment: Did explain in parentheses, but added screenshots anyway for clarity.

Comment: Is this run in ios 7?

Comment: iOS 7.1. Did you read my question?

Comment: that's why, I asked this question. It's not worked with 7.1 means, it may work with ios7.0?

Comment: _"while working fine with prior versions"_ means yes, it works in iOS 7.0, 6.1, etc.

Comment: Also, `[slider setThumbTintColor:color]` does't have any effect, but that's probably a different issue.

Comment: What is the view hierarchy of the slider? When do you set tint color?

Comment: The slider is placed in a standard UIView from IB. The color is set dynamically in the slider's _Value Changed_ event.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found this workaroud:

Create a 1x1px `UIImage` from a `UIColor` on the fly:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
[color setFill];
UIRectFill(rect);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and then

```
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Looks like an expensive solution but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks... works perfectly as a workaround until Apple fix this

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Reported this bug and it's already well known. Hopefully they will fix it soon...

Comment: I'm using the stock `UISlider` class. The `MPVolumeView` does use an `UISlider` object, so our problems are related.

Comment: Yes, I know. Just wanted to clarify what your are trying to achieve. I've build a project where I'm using a UISlider and customized it too. But I'm not sure if I set the MaxTintColor myself. I will check this and give a response..

Comment: I've tried to add a comment above but the system said I must have 50 reputation to be able doing this. Sorry

Comment: In my case the tint color is set dynamically in the slider's **Value Changed** event. (the color goes from green to red based on the slider value)

Comment: No no, every code is happening with a standard UISlider. It`s strange because changing the minTrackTintColor works well if for example slider.value > .5f

Comment: Do you have an official response from Apple? Any link that shows it's a known issue or any possible workaround? Thanks.

Comment: I've just opened a new bug report and got a notification that this bug is already known. if you want, you can try it yourself: http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
UIImage *sliderLeftTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"LeftImage.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
UIImage *sliderRightTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"RightImage.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

[sliderName setMinimumTrackImage: sliderLeftTrackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[sliderName setMaximumTrackImage: sliderRightTrackImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

> If you want to change thumb image the following code will work:

```
[sliderName setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ThumbImgName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sliderName setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ThumbImgName.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

> In same way, you can also use color instead of images.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I need to **dynamically** change the color of the slider based on the slider value.

Comment: I created images with colours and now I set images. Works fine.

Comment: @MichalJuriJurník Could you post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've created 2px images with the colour of slider track.

[image]

And then I set they as tracking images (here's with thumb image for iPad and iPhone)

```
UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider"];
UIImage *trackImage;

if (isiPad) {
    [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    trackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-bar-ipad"];
}
else {
    [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[self imageWithImage:thumbImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(27, 27)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[self imageWithImage:thumbImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(27, 27)] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    trackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-bar"];
}

[[UISlider appearance]  setMinimumTrackImage:trackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance]  setMaximumTrackImage:trackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And that's all. Same solution as msmq I guess. And you can see both ways how to make a large image - two images way and scaling way.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What we are missing here is the **dynamic** factor. E.g. the slider goes from red to green based on its value.

Comment: Oh sry, now I see that. If you need to have slider with one green colour and one red colour you could just change min and max track images.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late, but - here is the answer

You should read description of setter:

> The color used to tint the standard maximum track images. Setting this
>   property removes any custom maximum track images associated with the
>   slider.

Also this applicable only for `maximum color`, because `minimum` setter just change titntColor:

> The color used to tint the standard minimum track images.

This mean that slider use some image for maximum track and if u just set tint color nothing will be changes (nothing can't be tinted).

[image]

Solution (thanks to @user623396):

```
UIImage *currentSliderMaximumImage = self.slider.currentMaximumTrackImage;

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, currentSliderMaximumImage.size.width, currentSliderMaximumImage.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
[[[DynamicUIService service] currentApplicationColor] setFill];
UIRectFill(rect);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.slider setMaximumTrackImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

As result u will get

[image]