# MPVolumeView customization issues

Tags: ios, ios7, mpvolumeview

I am working on a radio application, and need to customize the volume tracker colors.

```
    myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(26, 292, 268, 23)];

    [self.view addSubview: myVolumeView];
    for (id current in myVolumeView.subviews) {
        if ([current isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
            UISlider *volumeSlider = (UISlider *)current;
            volumeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
            volumeSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            //[volumeSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"volTrack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
```

If I run the code like this, it causes a weird bug: [image: broken image]

But if I comment out the max track color, it works (although no customized color). [image]

Any remedies for this? I am running 7.1.1

Comment: I ran into this same issue while trying to customize the MPVolume control. Were you able to find a resolution for this? Thank you!

Comment: Turns out the same question was asked and I found the solution at the follow SO link to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345668/uislider-setmaximumtracktintcolor-in-ios-7-1

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
if ([current isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
     UISlider *volumeSlider = (UISlider *)current;
     volumeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
     volumeSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
     [volumeSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"volTrack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     // I think you should set these properties:
     [slider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filled ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"MDAudioPlayer.bundle"]]stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [slider setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:empty ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"MDAudioPlayer.bundle"]] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```