# UISlider with single bar color

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uislider

I cant believe i cant find answer online - this is what im trying to achieve- Single color for the UISlider bar(no matter where the thumb is)

*Dont mind the BG color*

[image: s]

, but all i can change is one size of the bar(Tint color i guess) :\

[image: s]

Any ideas how can i achieve single color all the way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UISlider setMaximumTrackTintColor in iOS 7.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345668/uislider-setmaximumtracktintcolor-in-ios-7-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set

*choice -1*

```
yoursliderName.minimumTrackTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
yoursliderName.maximumTrackTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

if choice no 1 is not work

*choice - 2*

see this already answered in stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345668/uislider-setmaximumtracktintcolor-in-ios-7-1)

additional [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683348/uislider-setmaximumtracktintcolor)

Comment: Simple as i thought it would be . Thanks buddy!