# Invalid Content error while drawing a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, cgcontext, uibezierpath

I am trying to make a simple circle in viewdidload with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIBezierPath* aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(100,100) radius:100 startAngle:M_PI/6 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:YES];


    [aPath fill];
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

I know this problem is already being discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599266/invalid-context-0x0-under-ios-7-0-and-system-degradation) but I can not relate. The error occurs at

```
[aPath fill];
```

Is this something related to the application lifecycle?

Comment: Is your program functioning correctly other than logging this error?

Comment: It is showing a blank view. No circle. App doesn't crash although.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that you have no context to draw the path into, and you must have one.

As this code is in a view controller, you need to decide which context you should be drawing into.

You can create a context yourself and draw your path into it, which would be beneficial, for example, if you wanted to create an image containing the path. That would be done using `CGBitmapContextCreate`.

Or, and probably more what you're looking for, by drawing the path into the view controllers view context. This is available in the `drawRect:` method. So, you would implement that in your custom view subclass and move your code there.

An alternative is to use a `CAShapeLayer`, created with the path (using the `CGPath`) and add that as a sublayer of the view controllers views layer. Then you don't need to worry about the context at all...

Comment: Thank you. Added a custom UIView and added these lines to the drawrect method.

Can I use the drawrect of main view?

Comment: If you make the main view of your custom class, yes (in the XIB / storyboard / loadView method)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to draw without drawRect() using `CAShapeLayer()` and `UIBezierPath()` In this case where there's no context, don't set the color with UIColor.setStroke(), and don't do path.stroke(), because the stroke operation is implied when you assign the path to the shapeLayer.

```
func addDiagonalLineLayer() {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.lineWidth = 1.0
    path.move(to:    CGPointMake(0, 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPointMake(maxW, maxH))
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```