# How to play video if user clicks the tableview item

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to be able to click on a `tableview` item and play the *video.so* I wrote some of the code for video player.I am using `MPMediaplayer` framework.I am using `json parser`.Using `json parser` to retrieve the data from **webserver** .My problem is if i click the `tableview` item I recieve the following exception:

**'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array'

```
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ba7012 0x15f6e7e 0x1b490b4 0x1c203a8 0x1ae59 0x813285 0x8134ed 0x121d5b3 0x1b66376 0x1b65e06 0x1b4da82 0x1b4cf44 0x1b4ce1b 0x249e7e3 0x249e668 0x763ffc 0xd66d 0x3a4770d 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

This is my code.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    urlsArray=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
-(void)loadData
{

    url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"urls”];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

    NSError *jsonError = nil;

    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

    if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])      
    {

    }
    else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
        NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]init];
        array=[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"video-urls"];        
        dataDictionary=[array objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);    
    }
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key1”]]; 
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key2”]]; 
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key3”]];
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key4”]];
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@“Key6”]];       
    NSLog(@"%@",urlsArray); 
} 
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // self.selectedIndex=indexPath.row;
    currentUrlsArr=[urlsArray[indexPath.row]lastPathComponent];    
    NSString *documentDirectoryPath=   [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];   
    NSString *filePath=[documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentUrlsArr];   
    NSURL *videoURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];  
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];   
    videoPlayerView.moviePlayer.fullscreen=TRUE;    
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];    
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];   
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];   
}
```

Comment: issue with you array that empty and you are trying to get value from Empty array.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",urlsArray); what did this line print?

Comment: hi now i got exception like this:  local WeeklyAudioPlayerTable[1605] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599266/invalid-context-0x0-under-ios-7-0-and-system-degradation

Comment: hi  @mohitpopat plz come to chat room.i want to chat with u as per my problem.plz come to iPhone/ipad chat room