# Having an error when using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext, uibezierpath

I use `UIBezierPath` to draw a line. But having an error
This is my code:

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
[aPath closePath];
aPath.lineWidth = 5;
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
[aPath stroke];
```

This is error:

> CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a
>   serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
>   invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation
>   of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599266/invalid-context-0x0-under-ios-7-0-and-system-degradation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than

```
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
```

use

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
```

Also you could do the same as-

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *aPath;

aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size*2, 0)];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(size, size*2)];
[aPath closePath];

shapeLayer.path = aPath.CGPath;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.fillColor = color;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = width;

[self addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: I used your second way. it worked. Thank you so much

Comment: @thinhvd omit [aPath fill];

Answer (score 0):

Add this like to **setStrokeColor**

`CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);`

Comment: did you replace it with  `[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In xcode add symbolic breakpoint to `CGPostError`. (Add symbolic breakpoint, and to Symbol field type `CGPostError`)

When error happen, debugger will stop code executions and you can check stack of methods calls and check parameters.

Also make sure you have imported `QuartzCode` framework.