# Got a very cryptic error message in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I was making a barplot in RStudio from a variable in a list that had 1048575 objects. The barplot was constructed like this

```
towers = cell_tracking$grid_pos #grid_pos is the variable, cell_tracking is the list
towers.freq = table(towers)
barplot(towers.freq, xlab = "tower IDs", ylab = "frequency"
```

Perhaps I used the wrong method because this is the error message I got

```
0x1016e8f20. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
invalid context and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability
and reliability
```

I'm not even sure that my barplot is the reason behind this error message, but it did appear right after I ran the code to make the barplot, so that seems like the most likely source. Does anyone know the reason behind this? Should I be scared? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I have no solution to offer, but it might be a consolation that others have obtained the same error message before. Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599266/invalid-context-0x0-under-ios-7-0-and-system-degradation) helps.

Comment: Does this happen in R from the plain R console or only in the R-Studio GUI? Is it consistently repeatable?

Comment: From the R-Studio GUI. I've run the same code repeatedly since then and the error hasn't appeared. Maybe it was just a strange anomaly :\